# How to send variable to widget from c++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

From code I want to assecc widget and and send string variable to it. But with my code I see only default value for it. Whet I set value in widget without code - it works.

Call method from another class:

```
  UChangeDialogBottomText* changeDialogBottomText = CreateWidget<UChangeDialogBottomText>(
    GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController(), UChangeDialogBottomText::StaticClass());
  if (changeDialogBottomText)
  {
    changeDialogBottomText->UpdateDialogBotton();
  }
```

**.h**

```
UCLASS()
class HOME_API UChangeDialogBottomText : public UUserWidget
{
  GENERATED_BODY()
  
public:
  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (BindWidget)) FString st_Name_Key;

  UFUNCTION()
  void UpdateDialogBotton();
};
```

**.cpp**

```
void UChangeDialogBottomText::UpdateDialogBotton()
{
  st_Name_Key = "core";
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Event Construct` pin the in the blueprint is only called once when the widget is created, not every time a variable changes. Therefore, if you want the `UpdateDialogBotton` method to change the text of the widget, then you have to call the `SetText` method in there. However, you will also need a reference to the text block widget in C++. Right now, you have a reference to it in blueprints. There are many ways to go about this, but the easiest way would be to make a new property in your header file like so,

```
class UTextBlock; // <-- new line

UCLASS()
class HOME_API UChangeDialogBottomText : public UUserWidget
{
  GENERATED_BODY()
  
public:
  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (BindWidget)) // <-- new line
  UTextBlock* name_Text_Block; // <-- new line

  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (BindWidget)) 
  FString st_Name_Key;

  UFUNCTION()
  void UpdateDialogBotton();
};
```

And then in that event construct method in the blueprint, assign the `name_Text_Block` C++ variable to the `Name` blueprint variable. After doing that, you can change the text of the widget through the `UpdateDialogBotton` method like so,

```
void UChangeDialogBottomText::UpdateDialogBotton()
{
  st_Name_Key = "core";
  if (name_Text_Block) {
    name_Text_Block->SetText(FText::FromString(st_Name_Key));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Now I need to send value of the variable from code to the widget, but is don't work. I can see id using printscreen like on the second screenshot.

Comment: @DimaKozyr Remember, Event Construct gets called when the widget is created, so no matter what you change the st name key variable to in the `UpdateDialogBotton` method, you won't see the updated value in Event Construct. You need to invoke your own blueprint function after `UpdateDialogBotton` is called or the blueprint Tick function, just for testing only, to see the new updated value.